# nginx transmit udp package in windows platform

Tags: windows, nginx, udp

I want to use nginx-1.13.12 to transmit UDP message package in windows platform, but it can't work. when i start nginx, it show error in /logs/error.log. The detail info is 
**[emerg] 13404#13956: the invalid "udp" parameter in D:\soft_install\nginx-1.13.12/conf/nginx.conf:26**

The flowing is my nginx.conf file. **I want to know whether nginx can transmit udp package in windows.**

```
#user  nobody;
worker_processes  1;
#error_log  logs/error.log;
#error_log  logs/error.log  notice;
#error_log  logs/error.log  info;
#pid        logs/nginx.pid;
events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}
stream {
    log_format  main  '$remote_addr - [$time_local] "';
    upstream dns {
       server 223.3.71.149:5801 weight=2;
       server 223.3.71.149:5802 weight=3;
    }
    server {
        listen 5800 udp;
        proxy_responses 1;
        proxy_timeout 10s;
        proxy_pass dns;
        access_log  logs/access_dns.log  main;
        error_log logs/error_dns.log;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I got the same error on windows. turns out, nginx on windows does not support udp proxy.

> The UDP proxy functionality is not supported. [-http://nginx.org/en/docs/windows.html#known_issues](http://nginx.org/en/docs/windows.html#known_issues)